# Understanding the relationship between glutDisplayFunc and glutPostRedisplay

Tags: opengl, glut

When reading the redbook I found:

> glutDisplayFunc(void (*func)(void)) is
>   the first and most important event
>   callback function you will see.
>   Whenever GLUT determines that the
>   contents of the window need to be
>   redisplayed, the callback function
>   registered by glutDisplayFunc() is
>   executed. Therefore, you should put
>   all the routines you need to redraw
>   the scene in the display callback
>   function.
>
> If your program changes the contents
>   of the window, sometimes you will have
>   to call glutPostRedisplay(), which
>   gives glutMainLoop() a nudge to call
>   the registered display callback at its
>   next opportunity

Which are times in which glutPostRedisplay() should be called? From this paragraph, I don't understand why its functionality is needed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

glutDisplayFunc is called whenever your window must be redrawn. This includes the time when one calls glutPostRedisplay :)

When does a window need to be redrawn?

- When its size changes
- when it becomes visible
- when some parts of it become visible
- when it is moved
- etc

But what if your display function paints a triangle at position x;y where x;y; are determined by the mouse position? In this case you must ask the system to redraw the window whenever the mouse is moved right? That's why you'll call glutPostRedisplay from MouseFunc(). Actually when you call glutPostRedisplay, the redraw event is queued along with other window-events, like mouse click ets. Essentially what your mainLoop does it pick events from that queue and call their handlers

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't call glutDisplayFunc instead of glutPostRedisplay in the case you mention considering glutPostRedisplay eventually ends up calling glutDisplayFunc. What's the importance of the queue? Can it delay rendering while waiting for a condition?

Comment: @omgzor: In the above example, you could do that. But that's not the best choice. You see, it's better not call it directly but put it in a queue. If for example you want animation and call displayFunc directly from displayFunc, your program will not respond. Because you will have blocked the loop. That's why it's best to post the event and let the main loop handle it in its turn

Comment: @omgzor: It won't delay rendering. It will delay everything else :)

Answer (score 4):

The function you pass to `glutDisplayFunc` is only called it is needed: that means when the window is resized, or when an another window has hidden it. If you use `glutMouseFunc`, for instance, you perhaps want to update (redraw) your window content according to that clic. Also, if you draw animations, you need to call `glutPostRedisplay` from your idle function.