# why not display in openGL?

Tags: opengl

```
int main(int argc,char * argv[]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    glutInit(&argc,argv);

    // Setup GLUT
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB     | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
    glutInitWindowSize (window_width,window_height);
    glutCreateWindow (window_title);
    graphics_init ();

    // Initialize Runtime variables
    initialize();

    // callbacks
    glutReshapeFunc(&reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(&display);
    glutMouseFunc(&mouse);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}


void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y ){
    if(state == GLUT_DOWN){
         draw_method_two(); // draw objects here using method 2
            glFlush();

    }else{
        current_point_i = -1;
    }
}

void display(){
    // Clear Viewport
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    draw_method_one(); ///// using method 1 to draw objects

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

There are two methods to draw objects. in `mouse()`, `draw_objects_two` is used to draw the objects when mouse is clicked.  However, the objects shown in the window are still created by `draw_method_one`. I use `glFlush` in the `mouse()`function. but why it is not displayed in screen?

**Update:**

from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206472/understanding-the-relationship-between-glutdisplayfunc-and-glutpostredisplay), it says:

`The function you pass to glutDisplayFunc is only called it is needed: that means when the window is resized, or when an another window has hidden it. If you use glutMouseFunc, for instance, you perhaps want to update (redraw) your window content according to that clic. Also, if you draw animations, you need to call glutPostRedisplay from your idle function.`

So why `glutDisplayFunc()` is called in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your mouse function nothing is drawn, because you only call `glFlush` but you don't swap buffers (wtih `glutSwapBuffers`). Therefore you only draw to the back buffer, which is not presented. Next time GLUT calls display, the back buffer is overwritten there and finally presented by calling `glutSwapBuffers`.

But you should not draw anything in another method than the `glutDisplayFunc` callback, anyway. Just set some flag in the mouse function (like ssell suggested) and call `glutPostRedisplay`. Your updated question is correct, display is only called when neccessary, therefore you have to call `glutPostRedisplay` whenever you change something and want this to update the screen.

And by the way, you should usually not need to call `glFlush`, which should already be done by the buffer swap.

Comment: My understanding of `glFlush` is to send buffer to GPU? But my understanding should be not correct according to your explanation. What does `glFlush` do?

Comment: @Sean It actually just flushes the command buffer (as GL commands may be buffered in some abstract client-server-architecture) so that every command really gets executed. I never completely understood its use though, I have to admit. I think its some relict of the past. But when drawing in double buffered mode (which you usually do), everything is drawn to the back buffer and this buffer is then copied (or swapped) to the visible front buffer at once, to reduce flickering. This is usually done by an OS function, or in this case GLUT's wrapper around such a function.

Comment: so when I use `glFlush()`, only the front buffer is sent to screen to display because GL command buffer only refers to (or only knows) front buffer. Does my understanding correct? Thanks.

Comment: If I do not want the objects in `mouse` to display, do I need to call `glFlush` in `mouse()`?

Comment: OpenGL operations may be buffered or internally rearranged before they are sent to the renderer. glFlush() makes sure that all commands executed so far are sent to the renderer without further interference with what comes after; it's an artifact from the design decision that OpenGL is network transparent (through X11/GLX) and like all networking systems, you must flush the buffer to make sure, things are actually sent. glFinish() waits until all pending OpenGL operation has been finished, which includes a flush. Swapping a double buffer requires are OpenGL operation to be finished.

Comment: @Sean No! everything is only drawn to the back buffer (`glFlush` doesn't have anything to do with that). The back buffer is only presented (and therefore finally drawn what you rendered) when you call `glutSwapBuffers`. But like I said, don't draw in your mouse function. Just set some flag to tell the display function to draw something different and call `glutPostRedisplay`.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that no matter what, every loop `draw_method_one( )` is being called. When you click the mouse, `draw_method_two( )` is called only once, and so during the next loop the screen is redrawn using method one.

To get your desired result, do something like this:

```
bool drawFirstMethod = true;

...

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y )
{
    //toggle draw modes
    if( state == GLUT_DOWN )
    {
        if( drawFirstMethod )
            drawFirstMethod = false;
        else
            drawFirstMethod = true;
    }

    ...
}

display( )
{
    ...

    if( drawFirstMethod )
        draw_method_one( );
    else
        draw_method_two( );

    ...
}
```

Comment: Why `every loop draw_method_one( ) is being called`? I just click once and `display()` will be still called?

Comment: Because of `glutDisplayFunc( &display );` When GLUT is running (you do this by calling `glutMainLoop( );`), each loop it is calling `display( )` to render your scene.

Comment: do you mean `glutDisplayFunc()` is called continuous even if I do nothing? If so, why sometimes do we need to explicitly call `glutPostDisplay()` in functions such as `glutMouseFunc`? Because eventually `glutDisplyFunc()` will be called. I am very new to openGL. Sorry to such basic questions. Thank you.

Comment: @Sean `display` is definitely not called continously, but only when needed, therefore you need to call `glutPosRedisplay` from the mouse function.