# GLUT only runs display callback once and doesn't output to terminal

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

My GLUT program is behaving very unexpectedly. All it does (all it should do) is clear the screen blue and draw a purple triangle receding into the distance.

First and foremost, here is my code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>

class Ground{
private:
    float zpos;
public:
    Ground(){
        zpos = -5.0f;
    }
    void Render(){
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,1.0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(0,0,zpos);
        glVertex3f(0,1,zpos);
        glVertex3f(1,1,zpos);
        glEnd();
        zpos -= 0.1f;
    }
};

class Skybox{
public:
    Skybox(){

    }
    void Render(){
        glClearColor(0.5, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
};

Skybox s;
Ground g;
void init(void) 
{
    s = Skybox();
    g = Ground();
    glShadeModel (GL_SMOOTH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glViewport(0,0,glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT));
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60,glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH)/glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT),0.1,100);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void display(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hi";
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glClearDepth(1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    s.Render();
    g.Render();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize( 800, 600 ); 
    glutCreateWindow ("Umm");
    init ();
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

However, the code does not work as expected - the purple triangle does not recede into the distance, it stays still, and the simple `cout` doesn't even do anything! (But somehow, all of the code after it in the display function is executed, but only once?)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a timer callback to post a redisplay every now and again:

```
void timer( int value )
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
}
```

Otherwise `display()` will only be called when the OS feels like it, usually [after an expose/damage/paint event (like a window resize, or exposing more of the window by moving another window off of it)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4206504/44729).

All together:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>

class Ground{
private:
    float zpos;
public:
    Ground(){
        zpos = -5.0f;
    }
    void Render(){
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,1.0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(0,0,zpos);
        glVertex3f(0,1,zpos);
        glVertex3f(1,1,zpos);
        glEnd();
        zpos -= 0.1f;
    }
};

class Skybox{
public:
    Skybox(){

    }
    void Render(){
        glClearColor(0.5, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
};

Skybox s;
Ground g;
void init(void) 
{
    s = Skybox();
    g = Ground();
    glShadeModel (GL_SMOOTH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glViewport(0,0,glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT));
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60,glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH)/glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT),0.1,100);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void display(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hi";
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glClearDepth(1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    s.Render();
    g.Render();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer( int value )
{
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize( 800, 600 ); 
    glutCreateWindow ("Umm");
    init ();
    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May I ask why the "Hi" is never displayed? Is it because it is not part of the main thread?

Comment: @acer: [Workin' fine on my end](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2HN03.png).  Not sure how your setup differs.